# Determine if function call is first from Query VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there a way to determine whether or not a function has been called for the first time from a query in MS Access? I have a query that includes a field generated from a VBA function, however some initialisation is required.

To avoid doing this for every record the query produces, I'm wondering if there is a way to determine that the function call is from the first record in the query.

Comment: I think you might need to restructure your logic, e.g., a button that first does the initialization and then calls the query. I can think of problems with that too, but it might work.

Comment: The query is used so often in so many places that unfortunately a solution like that isn't all that feasible and probably a bit confusing for end users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private lastID As Integer

Function query_function(inputID As Integer) As Integer
  If (lastID <> inputID) Then
    Dim compareRST As DAO.RecordSet
    Set compareRST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT LAST MyTable.ID FROM MyTable;")
    lastID = compareRST!ID
    ' Do initialisation here
  End If
 ' Do other stuff here

End Function
```

MoveLast is the same value that LAST returns, but slower. The main problem is that the table is re-sorted to primary key order when you compact the database, so if the records are not added in primary key order, after compacting MoveLast will go to a different record.

The other problem is that for complex queries, with subordinate sub-queries, the LAST clause may be applied at the wrong place. If Id is simple incrementing, you can use MAX instead of LAST, but for simple queries like that shown it doesn't matter.

```
Select queryfunction(1) as a, queryfunction(1) as b from mytable
```

will call this function 4 times.

Each time this functioned is mentioned in the parent query, it will be called twice (or more? It's been a while).

I'm not sure if that is what you are trying to do, so I don't know what logic to suggest, but because it's called multiple times for each line, the function you posted will probably not do exactly what you think it does.

Comment: Thank you, the recalling of the function was something that I found happened a bit. Otherwise it worked. That should be a pretty easy thing to fix. Also will switch to `LAST`. I was in a bit of a rush and forgot what the actual SQL for that was so just used `.MoveLast`. Though in your `If` statement should it be `<>` or `=`?

Answer (score 2):

Use a public static Boolean variable.

```
Public Static isInit as Boolean

Public Function myUDF()
    If not isInit Then
        ' initializing code
        IsInit = True
    End if
    ' do stuff
End function
```

The public variable needs to be declared at the top of a regular module after any option statements and before any subs/functions.

Since you're using this query as a source for Forms and Reports, you could refactor your code so you can call the initialization of the function on form/report load, then set isInit to False on form/report unload. At this point though, you should probably think about if a class better fits your needs, or if there is a pure SQL solution to fit your needs.

```
Private Sub FormName_Load()
    Call udf_initialize
End Sub

Private Sub FormName_Unload()
    isInit = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Though in that case how do I determine when the query is finished so I can set init to false again?

Comment: Depends on how you're calling the query. Are you using vba to execute the query? You could just set isInit to false as the next step.

Comment: Note that the isInt var declare of static can be inside the function. In other words, static works for local vars.

Comment: @ckuhn203 unfortunately not. The query in question is used to generate some ordering for otherwise arbitrary strings. These results are used as source records for reports and forms.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I recommend posting a separate question to see if there's a SQL solution to your sorting problem.

Comment: Thanks. It's still probably not entirely suitable for what I have, being it such an important query used in pretty much every aspect of what is a large and complex system. I might try looking into the SQL or class solutions for it. Though hopefully this solution might help someone else.

Comment: You're welcome! I really do urge you to look for a SQL solution to this. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

OK. So in the end, this is how I solved it. Not the best method. If someone has a better one, I'd really appreciate it.

It's actually pretty hacky and probably prone to failure, it makes the assumption that the Query will try to look at the tables in the same order we would going through a recordset. That way, we can simply get the first value from the recordset, compare it, and if it's the same, assume we're looking at the first query. It also is not as efficient as it could be, creating a recordset and running an extra query every time. Though at least for me, it's slightly more efficient.

```
Function query_function(inputID As Integer) As Integer
    Dim compareRST As DAO.RecordSet
    Set compareRST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT MyTable.ID FROM MyTable;")
    If compareRST![ID] = inputID Then
        ' Do initialisation here
    End If
    ' Do other stuff here
    compareRST.close
End Function
```

---

**Edit - Slightly better solution that works on a similar principal**

Instead of creating a new query for each record, create the query to find the end, and then prepare to initilize when we reach it.

```
Private lastID As Integer

Function query_function(inputID As Integer) As Integer
  If lastID = 0 Then
    Dim compareRST As DAO.RecordSet
    Set compareRST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT MyTable.ID FROM MyTable;")
    compareRST.MoveLast
    lastID = compareRST!ID
    ' Do initialisation here
  End If
  ' Do other stuff here

  If lastID = inputID Then
    lastID = 0
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Do you realize that this has to execute for every row in your result set? I'm not asking you to accept my answer. I'm just calling out that this will be terribly inefficient as your database grows.

Comment: @ckuhn203 I'm well aware of that. However the initialisation itself invovles several more complex SQL calls that, with the database at it's reasonable size already, slows it down a fair deal. Right now, it's one simple SQL call every entry, vs. many complex SQL calls at the same time. It's not ideal, but the situation isn't ideal in the first place. Hopefully I'll be able to come back later to build a slightly more optimal solution, though until then, It's not pretty, though it'll have to do.